# how to inflate a view class in main.xml

Tags: android, xml, view, custom-view

How could i inflate my custom view using the main.xml file? I thought it carried the format of

```
<com.blah.project.MainClass.innerClass />
```

but I cant seem to get the fully qualified name of my inner class right. My customView is inside of my Main.java file, anyone know how I could properly reference it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is , but what i was missing is that in order for it to be inflated, the view must be declared static.

Answer (score 0):

try `<view class="com.blah.project.MainClass$innerClass" ... />`
or separate the view class.